# JsonConvert.DeserializeObject object from API using Webclient that could be one of 2 Object types

Tags: c#, json, object, serialization, dynamic

I am trying to access the FitBit API, with C# .Net Core 3.1

https://dev.fitbit.com/build/reference/web-api/sleep/

However, for sleep data, it could return the SleepJSON object or a  Meta object that will have a retry duration

```
{
    "meta": {
        "retryDuration": 3000,
        "state": "pending"
    }
}
```

If I didn't have to deal with this Meta object I would have simply done this which works as long as I do not get the other.

`var response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SleepJSON>(await wc.DownloadStringTaskAsync($"{url}"));`

I am fairly new to API work and have tried using dynamic however I am falling over when trying to determine which was returned and then converting them into the object type to use.

I am really at a loss on how to handle this situation of 2 possible return Object types.

Comment: Try and deserialize it is one type. If it fails, try the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do not know which object you are getting (and really good APIs either avoid this behavior or use headers to give you hints as to how to read the content), rather than completely deserialize the content, you can parse the response into a [JObject](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm), check the top level property, and choose the appropriate path based on its exisistance.

```
var json = await wc.DownloadStringTaskAsync($"{url}");

var jObject = JObject.Parse(json);
if (jObject.Property("meta") != null)
{
    // handle meta here
    meta = jObject.ToObject<MetaResponse>();
}
else
{
    // you can fully deserialize the normal path here
    response = jObject.ToObject<SleepJSON>();
}
```

Comment: This seems to be the answer I'm having success with a slight modification

                    if (jObject.Property("meta") != null)
                    {
                        meta = jObject.ToObject<MetaResponse>();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        response = jObject.ToObject<SleepJSON>();
                    }
Thank you @David L

Comment: @bandworthy happy to help and apologies for the loose syntax.  I've updated my answer to be a bit more consistent.